# Try install gitlab 6-5-stable, but have a 403 Forbidden

Tags: ruby, apache, gitlab, centos6

I followed all the installation process, but when I try to access the url gitlab an error displays "403 You do not have permission to access / on this server."

bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production

```
System information
System: CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
Current User: root
Using RVM: yes
RVM Version: 1.21.7
Ruby Version: 1.9.3p448
Gem Version: 1.8.25
Bundler Version:1.3.5
Rake Version: 10.1.0

GitLab information
Version: 6.5.1
Revision: 2ffa03a
Directory: /home/git/gitlab
DB Adapter: mysql2
URL: http://git.intranet.ecore.com.br
HTTP Clone URL: http://git.intranet.ecore.com.br/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL: git@git.intranet.ecore.com.br:some-project.git
Using LDAP: yes
Using Omniauth: no

GitLab Shell
Version: 1.8.0
Repositories: /home/git/repositories/
Hooks: /home/git/gitlab-shell/hooks/
Git: /usr/bin/git
```

bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production

```
Checking Environment ...

Git configured for git user? ... yes
Has python2? ... yes
python2 is supported version? ... yes

Checking Environment ... Finished

Checking GitLab Shell ...

GitLab Shell version >= 1.7.9 ? ... OK (1.8.0)
Repo base directory exists? ... yes
Repo base directory is a symlink? ... no
Repo base owned by git:git? ... yes
Repo base access is drwxrws---? ... yes
update hook up-to-date? ... yes
update hooks in repos are links: ... can't check, you have no projects
Running /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/check
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:216: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin in PATH, mode 042777
Check GitLab API access: FAILED. code: 403
gitlab-shell self-check failed
  Try fixing it:
  Make sure GitLab is running;
  Check the gitlab-shell configuration file:
  sudo -u git -H editor /home/git/gitlab-shell/config.yml
  Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.

Checking GitLab Shell ... Finished

Checking Sidekiq ...

Running? ... yes
Number of Sidekiq processes ... 1

Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

Checking LDAP ...

LDAP users with access to your GitLab server (only showing the first 100 results)
rake aborted!
SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/net-ldap-0.3.1/lib/net/ldap.rb:1132:in `connect'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/net-ldap-0.3.1/lib/net/ldap.rb:1132:in `wrap_with_ssl'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/net-ldap-0.3.1/lib/net/ldap.rb:1169:in `setup_encryption'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/net-ldap-0.3.1/lib/net/ldap.rb:1116:in `initialize'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/net-ldap-0.3.1/lib/net/ldap.rb:634:in `new'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/net-ldap-0.3.1/lib/net/ldap.rb:634:in `search'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/net-ldap-0.3.1/lib/net/ldap.rb:1044:in `search_root_dse'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/net-ldap-0.3.1/lib/net/ldap.rb:1095:in `paged_searches_supported?'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/net-ldap-0.3.1/lib/net/ldap.rb:619:in `search'
/home/git/gitlab/lib/tasks/gitlab/check.rake:702:in `print_users'
/home/git/gitlab/lib/tasks/gitlab/check.rake:692:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => gitlab:check => gitlab:ldap:check
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: ```Git configured for git user? ... no
Try fixing it:
sudo -u git -H git config --global user.name "GitLab"
sudo -u git -H git config --global user.email "gitlab@hpsdev01.intranet.ecore.com.br"
For more information see:
doc/install/installation.md in section "GitLab" Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.```  You need to configure git for the git user.

Comment: All commands were executed by git User

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the errors that are displayed by executing:

```
bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production
```

The problem was in the Nginx configuration, below is the configuration that I realized:

```
upstream gitlab {
  server unix:/home/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket;
}

server {
  #  listen *:80 default_server;         # e.g., listen 192.168.1.1:80; In most cases *:80 is a good idea
  server_name git.intranet.ecore.com.br;     # e.g., server_name source.example.com;
  server_tokens off;     # don't show the version number, a security best practice
  root /home/git/gitlab/public;

  # individual nginx logs for this gitlab vhost
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

  location / {
    # serve static files from defined root folder;.
    # @gitlab is a named location for the upstream fallback, see below
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @gitlab;
  }

  # if a file, which is not found in the root folder is requested,
  # then the proxy pass the request to the upsteam (gitlab unicorn)
  location @gitlab {
    proxy_read_timeout 300; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    proxy_connect_timeout 300; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    proxy_redirect     off;

    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;

    proxy_pass http://gitlab;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin in PATH, mode 042777`

It seems you have some issues with the permissions being too open. Fix that by going to `/home/git/gitlab/` and run:

- `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 644` (all files 644 recursively)
- `find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 755`  (all directories 755 recursively)
- `sudo -u git -H chmod o-rwx config/database.yml` (extra security for the database)

If that is not the case then maybe its SELinux. You can check that quickly by disabling it temporarily:

```
setenforce 0
```

If the 403 error goes away then enable it back (`setenforce 1`) and see [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/tree/master/web-server/apache) at the SELinux section how to make it work.